# Here I tried to find the general solution of the following linear differential equation but couldn't correctly find the answer .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(D^2 + 2i + 1)y=0$$

here's what I've done so far, obtained auxiliary equation:

$$m^2+2im+1=0$$

Roots:

$$m_1=i(\sqrt2-1)\\m_2=-i(1+\sqrt2)$$

Which should give the general solution as:

$$y=c_1e^{i(\sqrt2-1)}+c_2e^{-i(1+\sqrt2)}
$$

*Which is no way similar to the expected answer!*

**Expected answer** $$c_1e^{2x}+e^{-x}\{c_2\cos(x\sqrt3)+c_3\sin(x\sqrt3)\}$$

Comment: Welcome to the site ! Be sure that a lot of people are ready to **help** you but no one will do your homework. Explain what you already tried and did, show your efforts and explain where you are stuck. I am afraid that, as it is, you question will be closed very quickly because totally off-topic.

Comment: are you sure you copied correctly this differential equation ? because WA gives this complicated solution http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B(2i%2B1)y%3D0

Answer (score 2):

$$(D^2 + 2i + 1)y=0 \implies y''+( 2i + 1)y=0$$
You did a little mistake here
$$m^2+2im+1=0$$
The characteristic polynomial should be
$$m^2+(2i+1)=0$$
You can find the correct answer now

Answer (score 1):

The expected answer has 3 basis functions, and thus should be for an ODE of order 3. Its characteristic polynomial should be
$$
(λ-2)(λ+1-i\sqrt3)(λ+1+i\sqrt3)=(λ-2)(λ^2+2λ+4)=λ^3-8
$$
corresponding to the ODE $(D^3-8)y=0$. No quadratic factor looks similar to your ODE.

Answer (score 1):

From the expected answer you could see that $\ m_1=2\ $ and $\ m_2=-1\pm \sqrt3\ i\  $.

That means $\ (m-2)(am^2+bm+c)=0 \ $ is the characteristic equation of the ODE

Then by quadratic formula $$-1\pm\sqrt3 \ i=\frac{-b\ \pm\ \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

You can figure out $\ a=\frac12\ $,$\ b=1\ $,$\ c=2\ $

The characteristic equation is:
$$(m-2)\left(\frac12m^2+m+2\right)=0 \implies \frac12m^3-4=0\implies m^3-8=0\\(m-2)(m^2+2m+4)=0$$

So the ODE must be, based on your expected answer:

$$y'''-8=0$$

So maybe you wrote something wrong.

Comment: An easier way is to note that the 3 roots are proportional to the 3 cube roots of unity, i.e $m_n = 2e^{i2 n \pi/3}$. Hence $m^3 = 8$ is the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Thanks @Dylan you're right but i wanted to do it a intuitive way for him. Because there wasn't any interpretation of the question  i answered with what he gave.